# Box 2.0 API Pardon the Pause Response

Tags: php, curl, box-api

I'm new to the Box API and especially Box API 2.0. After a few hours of working out the kinks of my cURL calls and all the rest of the code I finally got everything straightened out. Then the very next call that I made returned an HTML response that says -

Box Pardon the Pause
Your Box account is temporarily down — but you shouldn't be — because we'll be up and running soon.
Thanks for your patience ... and for being the most important part of Box.

Its been over an hour and I'm still getting this response, I tried waiting to see if it was some sort of throttling issue on my part, but I've only called the API probably 50 times or so since I started working 3-4 hours ago. Any thoughts/help?

```
$url = "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0";
$headers[] = "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=$key,auth_token=$token";
//curl https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/FOLDER_ID \
//-H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN"

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, "CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Can you specify which API calls are causing this error? The HTML page is not the intended response, we should be sending back our [normal error objects](http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors) in these cases.

Comment: Yea, I'm trying to make the https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0 call in the API.

Comment: ^the get folder information GET call

Comment: And now that I implemented it, the add folder as well.

Comment: Are you still experiencing these errors? I haven't been able to reproduce on my account.

Comment: Yes I am, I'm going to edit this to show the call I am making, hopefully that will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result is this. I was calling the API wrong because of the way that Box expects the authorization parameters in the header. The correct way to make calls to the Box API is as follows :

```
    $key = $box["API_Key"];
    $token = $box["Auth_Token"];
    $url = "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/" . "0";
    $headers[] = "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=$key&auth_token=$token";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, "CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
```